# Terraform add Route Rule to an existing route table - Oracle OCI provider

Tags: terraform, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I want to add a new route rule to an existing route table which is in different VCN and the route table has been created by other teams.

If I add any new route rule, it's been overwriting with all other existing route rules. I can get the route rules from data source. Now, how can I add new rule by looping with the rules I got it from data source.

```
      "route_rules" = [
        {
          "cidr_block" = ""
          "description" = ""
          "destination" = "0.0.0.0/0"
          "destination_type" = "CIDR_BLOCK"
          "network_entity_id" = "ocid1.internetgateway.oc1.phx.aaaaaaaa66a5u6h63c2vx4x4era"
        },
        {
          "cidr_block" = ""
          "description" = ""
          "destination" = "192.164.0.0/16"
          "destination_type" = "CIDR_BLOCK"
          "network_entity_id" = "ocid1.localpeeringgateway.oc1.phx.aaaaaxd6ffzyac74pwtzmadaycd344ua"
        },
        {
          "cidr_block" = ""
          "description" = ""
          "destination" = "193.168.0.0/16"
          "destination_type" = "CIDR_BLOCK"
          "network_entity_id" = "ocid1.localpeeringgateway.oc1.phx.aaaaaaavpjfi2cd7bnum3xcfdrylfnpa"
        },
        {
          "cidr_block" = ""
          "description" = ""
          "destination" = "192.168.0.0/16"
          "destination_type" = "CIDR_BLOCK"
          "network_entity_id" = "ocid1.localpeeringgateway.oc1.phx.aaaaaaotebnjfi2cd7bnum3xcfdrylfnpa"
        },
      ]
```

How can I add a new rule along with above rules?

```
Datasource,

data "oci_core_route_tables" "test_route_tables" {
    compartment_id = "ocid1.compartment.oc1..aaaaaap6foynzstr3qoqsgwt6gwfq"
    vcn_id = "ocid1.vcn.oc1.phx.amaaaaaawbmpx5iab6gjrszm7sybnn5n6zcs45f66q"
}


output "route" {

  value = data.oci_core_route_tables.test_route_tables
}
```

```
New rule to be added,

"CIDR block"= "192.176.0.0/16"
"destination_type" = "CIDR_BLOCK"
"network_entity_id" =  "ocid.ddd.oft"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to `import` the exisiting route rule into your terraform state, then match it accordingly in the config with the new route rule and apply the change. https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/oci/latest/docs/resources/core_route_table#import

More info on import can be found here - https://www.terraform.io/docs/import/index.html

Comment: No, actually I wanted to add new rule dynamically by mapping the data-source values.

Answer (score 0):

the output route is incomplete it should be like this

```
output "route" {
  value = data.oci_core_route_tables.test_route_tables.route_tables[0].route_rules
}
```

this will retrieve the first route table all route rules

you can check that also by exporting the state file.

```
terraform show -no-color > state.tmp
```